# SwiftUI @ObservedObject & @StateObject won't Update UI, some UI not showing up randomly

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have experienced an issue where I append item to the @Published var struct in ViewModel.
issue is : the current item I appended will not showing in the cartview but the data is actually appended and when I add the second item, the cartview will showing the first item I appended previously OR if you switch view then the UI is showing up. In the add event I have put dispatchque.main.asyc {}. this problem occurred randomly,i don't know what's wrong. I searched on Google and suspect it has to do with main thread, that's I added dispatchque,main.async to every button Event. but it still occurred.

my code follows MVVM pattern.

```
struct DrinkMenu: Identifiable,Codable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title : String
    var image: String
    var drink : [DrinkModel]
    
    
}

struct DrinkModel : Identifiable,Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var hasVariantSize : Bool
    var drinkName : String
    var price : Double
    var type : DrinkTypes
    var image : String
}

class OrderViewModel : ObservableObject {
@Published var cartDrinks : [CartDrinkVM] = []
func orderDrinks(name: String,price: Double,extra: String,extraPrice: Double,currentSize: String) {
        
        
        self.cartDrinks.append(CartDrinkVM(name:"\(currentSize)\(name)", price: price, extra: [DrinkExtra(extra: extra, price: extraPrice)], unit: 1, date: Date()))
        
    }
}
```

In the View there's two method to add the item

```
1: if drink sell by bottle : i use hasVariant Bool to indicate
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                withAnimation {
                                    if drink.hasVariantSize {
                                        showDrinkCardView.toggle()
                                        orderData.currentDrink = drink
                                        
                                    } else {

                                        orderData.orderDrinks(name: drink.drinkName, price: drink.price, extra: "", extraPrice: 0, currentSize: "")
                                    }

                                }
                            }
2: hasVariant size then showing secondary menu to add, with some extras requirement. code in secondary menu: 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            withAnimation {
                                orderData.orderDrinks(name: drink.drinkName, price: drink.price, extra: CurrentExtra.extra, extraPrice: CurrentExtra.price, currentSize: CurrentSizeSelcted)
                                    show.toggle()
                            }
                        }
```

this is the secondary menu for the drinks, if there's no size, it just added to the cart.
the layout for the app is very simple, left size is cartview and right size is browsing item view. it follows NavigationView structures .

[image]

code for drinkVM:

```
struct CartDrinkVM : Identifiable,Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var price : Double
    var extra : [DrinkExtra]
    var unit : Int
    var date : Date
}

struct DrinkExtra : Codable,Hashable {
    var extra : String
    var price : Double
}
what I did it 
transferring data from DrinkModel to DrinkVM plus extra options. 

func orderDrinks(name: String,price: Double,extra: String,extraPrice: Double,currentSize: String) {
        
        
        self.cartDrinks.append(CartDrinkVM(name:"\(currentSize)\(name)", price: price, extra: [DrinkExtra(extra: extra, price: extraPrice)], unit: 1, date: Date()))
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is `CartDrinkVM`?

Comment: CartDrinkVM is another struct to hold the appended item, because Spirits has mixer. my DrinkModel is for browsing purposes, It does not have mixer options. is this causing the problem? converting data between two structs?

Comment: show the code for `CartDrinkVM` and what you do with `OrderViewModel` in your view.

Comment: @workingdog I have included CartDrinkVM codes now. in my browsing Drink view I have ObservedObject to access the ViewModel. this injection goes all the views back to StateObject in Home View.

Comment: What is `DrinkMenuData` that isn't being observed anywhere in the `View`

Comment: DrinkMenuData doesn't require mutate, that's why I didn't observe it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution, but I figured out a workaround for this issue.
since my views are stacked under navigations view. every time I append one data, I switch to view 2 and back to original view.there's no strange behaviours.